# ASP.NET Core 3.0: The type or namespace name 'CreateDefaultBuilder' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

What am I using:

- .NET Core SDK 3.0.100
- Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.3.2

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project targeting netcoreapp3.0 and I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'CreateDefaultBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'Template.Host' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take another look at the error message:

> The type or namespace name 'CreateDefaultBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'Template.Host'...

When you write `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` in a namespace of `Template.Host`, the compiler assumes you mean `Template.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`.

There's a few options for fixing this:

1. Nest the `using` statement inside of your namespace:

   ```
    namespace Template.Host
    {
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

        // ...
    }
   ```
2. Alias the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host` type inside of your namespace:

   ```
    namespace Template.Host
    {
        using Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host;

        // ...
    }
   ```
3. Use the fully qualified name for the `Host` type:

   ```
    Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   ```

`Host` represents the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and is preferred over [`WebHost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0) in ASP.NET Core 3.0+.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: I am of such a lowly SO status I can’t comment on Kirk’s post. I wasn’t aware of Host being the preferred in 3.0. Anyway, Kirk’s answer should be the correct one**

You should be using WebHost (not Host) as follows:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Comment: @kirk is correct. All the default templates use the following code

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}